# How to use AudioPlayer to play a song without blocking?

Tags: python, audio-player

I am trying to use `AudioPlayer` but I can't figure it out.
First I import the library

```
from audioplayer import AudioPlayer
```

When I use it with `block=True` it works perfectly fine, but it waits for the track to end to continue the code, and I want them to work at the same time.

```
self.gearham=AudioPlayer("path/to/mp3").play(block=True)
```

When I make `block=False` I don't get any error, but no sound plays either.

```
self.gearham=AudioPlayer("path/to/mp3").play(block=False)
```

In the guide it says:

> Playback stops when the object is destroyed (GC'ed), so save a reference to the object for non-blocking playback.

However, I don't have any clue how to do that. I searched online and found some stuff about classes, but I barely understood it. I came up with this:

```
class AudioPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gearham=AudioPlayer("path/to/mp3").play
    def f(self):
        self.gearham

gearham=AudioPlayer()
gearham.f()
```

However, this didn't work, and the error I got was `__init__ requires 1 positional argument and was given 2`.